# Define two tables in c# with foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to make 2 tables : Teams and Projects
I want to make a 1 : n relationship between these two.
This is my code:
  //Creare tabela Projects

```
    public void CreareTabelaProjects() {
        string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects" + "(" + "id_project MEDIUMINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," + "name VARCHAR(30)," +
            "description VARCHAR(30)," + "FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES Teams(team_id)" + ");";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true) {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }

   //Creare tabela Teams

    public void CreareTabelaTeams() {
        string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teams" + "(" + "team_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," + "name VARCHAR(30)" + ");";
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }

    }
```

When i run this, an error occured saying this :
Key column 'team_id' doesn't exist in table. The application creates only the Team table. Any help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right query for Project Table

```
 string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects" + "(" + "project_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," + "team_id INT,"+"name VARCHAR(30)," +
            "description VARCHAR(30)," + "FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES Teams(team_id)" + ");";
```

Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: What's the difference? BTW this problems shows why you should NOT use string concatenation to create SQL statements. Why don't you create a SQL script file and execute it on the server anyway? Or just read its contents and call execute them as a single command?

Comment: The difference is that this query actually create the key team_id in the Projects table, while the original tried to define a foreign key on team_id while team_id wasn't defined within Projects

Answer (score 1):

Create the second table before the first one

Comment: I am creating the Teams first

Comment: private void UserForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _dbConnect.CreareTabelaTeams();
            _dbConnect.CreareTabelaProjects();
        }

Comment: The table being referenced needs to exist for creating the constraint. Another way would be create tables without constraints and then alter tables to add constraints in a separate query, that will be a bit more maintainable.

Comment: I thought this is the problem


    string query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Projects" + "(" + "project_id MEDIUMINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," + "name VARCHAR(30)," +
                "description VARCHAR(30)," + "FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Teams(team_id)" + ");";
I changed the team_id in Foreign key with Project_id. now it says : error  150. Cannot create Projects table

Comment: project_id is mediumint and team_id is int ensure both have the same datatype